# Не понимаю отрицательный промежуток

Tags: python

Увидел в источнике вот такую запись

```
def maskify(cc):
l = len(cc)
if l <= 4: return cc
return (l - 4) * '#' + cc[-4:]
```

Не понимаю, что значит от -4 до конца. Можете ли вы объяснить или посоветовать открытый источник.

Comment: 4 последних элементов списка.

Comment: т.е. до нуля? Отрицательные промежутки идут до нуля?

Comment: нет, от длины отнимается 4, и с этого индекса до конца списка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не промежуток, а индекс. Отрицательные индексы считаются с конца:

```
>>> l = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> l[-4:]
[7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> l[-6:-2]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
```